# flexible n dimensional index in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to get some elements from an n-dimensional matrix by using an index matrix `iM`. But this `n` is unknown.

Is it possible to get a flexible way to do something like:

```
if n == 1:
    value = M[iM[:]] # orM[iM[:, 0]]
elif n == 2:
    value = M[iM[:, 0], iM[:, 1]]
elif n == 3:
    value = M[iM[:, 0], iM[:, 1], iM[:, 2]]
```

UPDATE:
this can be done like:

```
value = M[[(iM[:, i]) for i in range(0, n)]]
```

Comment: Why is not `M[iM[:, 0]]` for `n == 1`?

Comment: it is also ok. The only thing is the dimension of the index Matrix is also changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate individual indicies lists using an explict `list`(or e.g. `tuple`) constructor, since that will automatically get the elements into different lists:

```
M[list(iM.T)] # or e.g. M[tuple(iM.T)]
```

Due to how the list is created (row-by-row) and the layout of your index matrix (where you want to get the indicies column-by-column) the index matrix `iM` needs to be transposed (`iM.T`) before it is turned into a list.